# How to split comma-separated words?

Tags: text, replace, cpu-word

How can i split my words in new line (i have a lot of them) currently separated with comma,
Example of my file contains words in a single line:

```
Viktor, Vajt, Adios, Test, Line, Word1, Word2, etc...
```

The the output file should look like:

```
Viktor
Vajt
Adios
Test
...
```

Comment: replace comma with newline character?

Comment: Well yes but i dont know the "new line character" command :)

Comment: Neither do i, they are different in different OS's - what are you using. Also, are you using a programming/scripting language to do this, or using some text editor program?

Comment: ya this is a really trivial thing to do, but we need to know the environment you are working in.

Comment: Win xp, office 2010, i can download some extra program if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using NotePad++, this can easily be done. See image below

[image]

Comment: Downloading it, let me try it in few minutes... :)

Comment: Download notepad++ anyways ... it is a must have tool if you do loads of scripting :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what language you are in but you could use an explode/split function which would create an array of values split at ','. Then you could loop through the array and append the new line special character "\n". You would wind up with something like:

```
$fileContentsAsString; //read file into string variable

$valuesArray = explode(',' $fileContentsAsString);

$outputString;
foreach($valuesArray as $item){
 $outputString .= $item . "\n";
}
```

Comment: fileContentsAsString.Replace(",","\n");

Comment: In this instance replace would have been sufficient vs. the process which i have outlined. Although if processing of the delimited strings is ever required explode() or split() comes in handy.

Answer (score 0):

If you – for some reason – want to stick with the doc Format (to keep formatting, etc.) you could use LibreOffice (http://de.libreoffice.org/) to do the following replacement:

[image: LibreOffice RegeEx replacement]

I agree installing LibreOffice just for this replacement would be overkill though.

Answer (score 0):

For a quick text edititng i'm using online tool (http://regexptool.org/). Also you can do it step by step ([screen](http://gyazo.com/43a2a511a397583c715b8b7e5cd6a47d)).